# Cloning from a repository that contains Bootstrap

Tags: git, twitter-bootstrap

What's the best method to clone from a repository that contains Bootstrap code.

Say, I am starting a project and I'd like to copy everything from https://github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate in my project directory.

I'm not really interested in keeping track of all the history from the boilerplate code.

Answer (score 0):

You can clone using git

```
git clone https://github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate myproject/boilerplate
```

Comment: But I wouldn't be able to do that if already have some initial files in my folder. Say .gitingore and a README.